# Do you really need the KeyTool to use an API like YouTube?

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

I was watching a tutorial today and in it, the teacher said to use a Key Tool to obtain the SHA1 fingerprint in order to get the API key. For some reason that seemingly has no fix, I could not bring up the Key Tool through the Android Studio terminal. Instead I skipped this step... and everything works fine. Why?... Why would this be a step if it is not necessary?

[This is the tutoria in question.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4NT5iBFuZs)

It seems like a step that does not matter if everything works fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding SHA1 fingerprints (you can add more than one) and package names restricts use of the API key only to an authorized apps. The API key will still work if this is left out but this adds an extra level of security.